# Remove xmlns=" " from XML with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrm:plugin source-default-namespace=""  cible-encodage="ISO-8859-1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm testplugin.xsd" xmlns:tech="http://www.moss.fr/2011/moteur-xrm" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:attribut="http://www.moss.fr/2012/attribut" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mcd="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:xrm="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" xmlns:variable="http://www.moss.fr/2012/variable" xmlns:doc="http://www.moss.fr/2011/documentation" xmlns:mtf2xsd="http://www.moss.fr/2010/mtf2xsd" xmlns:conv="http://www.moss.fr2010/conversion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:info="http://www.moss.fr/2011/information" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema">
<xrm:mapping occurs="xrm:mapping">
  <SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA xmlns=""
                                 info:obligatoire="true"
                                 occurs="/grappe"
                                 info:contexte="/grappe">
  </SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA>
 </xrm:mapping>
</xrm:plugin>
```

The element `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` is in the namespace `"urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"` then I just have to delete the `xmlns=" "`.

I tried this XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='']">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I thought the XSLT will use the namespace-uri from `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` but it changed nothing. I need to find a way to remove this `xmlns = " "` generally (i have a lot of XML document with `mapping` containing this "attribute" which creates a problem to validate with xsd).

Here you can find an other XML with the same problem but a different namespace :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrm:plugin xmlns:doc="http://www.moss.fr/2011/documentation"
        xmlns:info="http://www.moss.fr/2011/information"
        xmlns:xrm="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm"
        xmlns:attribut="http://www.moss.fr/2012/attribut"
        xmlns:variable="http://www.moss.fr/2012/variable"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tech="http://www.moss.fr/2011/moteur-xrm"
        xmlns:conv="http://www.moss.fr2010/conversion"
        xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo"
        xmlns:mcd="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo"
        xmlns="urn:SBEPlanDeVolSYSCA-schema"
        xmlns:SBEPlanDeVolSYSCA="urn:SBEPlanDeVolSYSCA-schema"
        xmlns:mtf2xsd="http://www.moss.fr/2010/mtf2xsd"
        source-default-namespace=""
        cible-encodage="ISO-8859-1">
<xrm:mapping>
  <SBEPlanDeVolSYSCA xmlns=""
                     info:obligatoire="true"
                     info:est-codage="true"
                     occurs="/grappe[ LieuOaci/aCodeOaci = $Codes_OACI_A_Traiter ]"
                     doc:description="On filtre les PDV qui ne concernent pas des plateformes définies en fichier de configuration"
                     param="Codes_OACI_A_Traiter"
                     info:contexte="/grappe[ LieuOaci/aCodeOaci = $Codes_OACI_A_Traiter ]">
  </SBEPlanDeVolSYSCA>
 </xrm:mapping>
</xrm:plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You XML shows this...

```
<SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA xmlns=""
```

This means `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` is in no namespace. It is not currently in the `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA`. The `xmlns=""` is overriding the default declaration on the parent element.

It is not a case of removing `xmlns=""` as a `xmlns` is not a normal attribute, but a namespace declaration. What you actually want to move `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` from being in no namespace, to being in the other namespace.

You can do this simply by doing this...

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema">
```

EDIT: If the default namespace is not known, you could just try getting the default namespace from the parent element

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{parent::*/namespace::*[name() = '']}">
```

However, this will not give the correct result if you had child elements under `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA`, for example, that also needed to be moved. In that case, try this which looks for the first ancestor that has a default namespace that is not empty:

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{ancestor::*[namespace::*[name() = '' and . != '']][1]/namespace::*[name() = '']}">
```